# Facebook like button ignoring URL depth

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have an URL like:
mywebsite.com/news/

and a facebook like button on each page. The problem is that when you like a page, the counter for all pages is affected, e.g.:

```
mywebsite.com/news/news-1/
mywebsite.com/news/?new_id=1
mywebsite.com/news/1/

mywebsite.com/news/news-2/
mywebsite.com/news/?new_id=2
mywebsite.com/news/2/
```

all this as well as mywebsite.com/news/ will have the increased counter as if you've "liked" them all.

I was using the < iframe > and switched to the < fb:like > but the bug still occurs.

I've found this thread: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=252714 where the people seemed to have the same problem that somehow got fix for one of them, but still persist for me.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This tool gives you specific information what is parsed by Facebook and where the error could be. I found it really helpful:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/